# Generate random sentences in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I'm very new to python and programming!

I need to write a program that has 4 tuples with 5 elements each.  One tuple should have verbs, one tuple should have nouns, one tuple should have adjectives, and one tuple should have adverbs.  Then I have to use a randomly generated numbers between 0 and 4 to pick one of the elements from each tuple. This is what I have so far:

```
import random

nouns = ("puppy", "car", "rabbit", "girl", "monkey")
verbs = ("runs", "hits", "jumps", "drives", "barfs") 
adv = ("crazily.", "dutifully.", "foolishly.", "merrily.", "occasionally.")
adj = ("adorable", "clueless", "dirty", "odd", "stupid")
num = random.randrange(0,5)
print (num)
```

Can someone show me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You can use that random number to select the corresponding element from each of the tuples. eg: `print nouns[num]`   https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences

Comment: A better solution would be to use `random.choice(nouns)`… but if your assignment requires you to use `random.randrange`, then you hav eto do it the way @ρss suggests.

Comment: I agree with @abarnert

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way for your understanding:

```
import random

nouns = ("puppy", "car", "rabbit", "girl", "monkey")
verbs = ("runs", "hits", "jumps", "drives", "barfs") 
adv = ("crazily.", "dutifully.", "foolishly.", "merrily.", "occasionally.")
adj = ("adorable", "clueless", "dirty", "odd", "stupid")
num = random.randrange(0,5)
print nouns[num] + ' ' + verbs[num] + ' ' + adv[num] + ' ' + adj[num]
```

Comment: Note that with this method, there are only 5 possible sentences, instead of the 625 possible sentences if you pick a random number for each word.

Answer (score 14):

You can use `random.choice` within a list comprehension then concatenate the selected list with `join`:

```
>>> l=[nouns,verbs,adj,adv]
>>> ' '.join([random.choice(i) for i in l])
'girl runs dirty crazily.'
>>> ' '.join([random.choice(i) for i in l])
'monkey hits clueless occasionally.'
```

Answer (score 3):

For a similar function to the accepted answer that returns all possible permutations:

```
import random

def make_random_sentence():
  nouns = ["puppy", "car", "rabbit", "girl", "monkey"]
  verbs = ["runs", "hits", "jumps", "drives", "barfs"]
  adv = ["crazily.", "dutifully.", "foolishly.", "merrily.", "occasionally."]
  adj = ["adorable", "clueless", "dirty", "odd", "stupid"]

  random_entry = lambda x: x[random.randrange(len(x))]
  return " ".join([random_entry(nouns), random_entry(verbs), random_entry(adv), random_entry(adj)])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select always the same index for each tupple, then try something like this:

```
import random
idx = random.randrange(0, 5)
print ("%s %s %s %s"%(nouns[idx], verbs[idx], adv[idx], adj[idx]))
```

If you want to get random elements for each tupple, the following should work:

```
import random
print("%s %s %s %s"%(random.choice(nouns), random.choice(verbs), random.choice(adv), random.choice(adj))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do as follows, using random.choice because it's a better choice than random.randrange...

```
words = (adj, nouns, verb, adv)
sentence = "".join(choice(word) for word in words)
```

Answer (score 1):

`random.choice` is to select a random thing from a list, tuple or similar container.
What the last line does is to select one random thing from each list, and make a new list from the choices. Then that list is printed. And being in a loop, this is done X number of times, whatever number the user inputs.

```
from random import choice 

nouns = ("puppy", "car", "rabbit", "girl", "monkey")
verbs = ("runs", "hits", "jumps", "drives", "barfs") 
adv = ("crazily.", "dutifully.", "foolishly.", "merrily.", "occasionally.")
adj = ("adorable", "clueless", "dirty", "odd", "stupid")

# asking user as to how many sentences he would like to generate 
for _ in range (int (input ("Enter integer value :"))): 
    print(list(map(choice, [nouns, verbs, adv, adj])))
```

```
Enter integer value :2
['car', 'barfs', 'dutifully.', 'odd']
['rabbit', 'runs', 'occasionally.', 'clueless']

[Program finished]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple one. If you want multiple sentences possible, use this:

```
nouns = ("puppy", "car", "rabbit", "girl", "monkey")
verbs = ("runs", "hits", "jumps", "drives", "barfs") 
adv = ("crazily.", "dutifully.", "foolishly.", "merrily.", "occasionally.")
adj = ("adorable", "clueless", "dirty", "odd", "stupid")

print(nouns[random.randrange(0,5)] + ' ' + verbs[random.randrange(0,5)] + ' ' 
+ adv[random.randrange(0,5)] + ' ' + adj[random.randrange(0,5)])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num = random.randrange(0,5)   
print (num)
```

Just gives you the random number you generated. You need to acess the tuples using that random number you generated like this.

```
print(nouns[num])
print(verbs[num])
print(adv[num])
print(adj[num])
```

Comment: Note that with this method, there are only 5 possible sentences, instead of the 625 possible sentences if you pick a random number for each word (same problem with [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29938988/16775594).